# Trying to understand what stand behinde Wisescript

Tags: installation, windows-installer, wise

I have two questions regarding to Wisescript,

(For those who don't familiar with Wisescirpt, it let you create installers, just like MSI)

Inside Wisescirpt Reference guide, there is a saying:

*"Because the WiseScript engine is written in C++, when you build a WiseScript, you
are building a C++ program"*

**So my first question is**: how can I see the c++ of my own wisescript?

The seconde question, is I didn't understand what it the relation between VBscript to Wisescript,
I know there is option to import VBscript into Wisescript, and aslo when I open the Wisescript with notepad, I can see code that's look like VBscript, but I don't it VBscript

**My second question in briefly is:** What is the relation between Wisescript and VBscript?  (I am interested to understand the interpreter, complier layers..)

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I see the c++ of my own
>   wisescript?

You can't, from the same reason you can't see the C++ code of an application. It refers to the language used to generate the installer.

> I didn't understand what it the
>   relation between VBscript to
>   Wisescript, I know there is option to
>   import VBscript into Wisescript

They are two different scripting languages. WiseScript is proprietary, VBScript is a Windows standard. The relation between them is set by the installation package: WiseScript generates an installer, VBScript can be used as a custom action in that installer.